# Bootstrap 5 Accordion button css not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have been trying to change accordion button color when it is not collapsed but it is not working, my accordion header is:

```
<h2 class="accordion-header" style="background-color: red" id="headingFour">
<button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
  <i class="icon_class%>"></i>
  <span class="nav-label">Nav-label</span>
</button>
```

And my css is looking like this:

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed){
color: #a7b1c2;
background-color: #293846;
}

.accordion-button:hover {
color: #a7b1c2;
background-color: #293846;
}
```

I have to say that the "hover" is working perfectly, but not when I click and uncollapsed it

Comment: Does this class really disappear? Did you tried to rebuild CSS output?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
  color: #a7b1c2;
  background-color: #293846;
}

.accordion-button:hover {
  color: #a7b1c2;
  background-color: #293846;
}



</style>

  <title>Accordion Example</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Your custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" style="background-color: red" id="headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <i class="active_module"></i>
          <span class="nav-label">Accordion Item 1</span>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          Content for Accordion Item 1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" style="background-color: red" id="headingTwo">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          <i class="inactive_module"></i>
          <span class="nav-label">Accordion Item 2</span>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          Content for Accordion Item 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Have a look into this code i had tried to color the accordion

Comment: Don't sure it's a good idea to setup bootstrap such way in rails 7. Also why do you decide to include JQuery to your answer?

Comment: Adding style on h2 have no effect, my idea is to add style on the button, as my hover is, and when the menu is expanded, accordion-button change color, this is no having any effect